# Github and CORS

Tags: angularjs, github, cors

I have my file xyz.xml in my github repository.

Now in my application i want to fetch this file xyz.xml so i am using $http() in angular but, as expected i get CORS as it is a different domain.

I know that we need to allow this on Server github to allow access from my application.

I want to know to enable CORS for GITHUB..?

Posting this question as i couldnt find any helpful answers here.

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Vishesh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Github supports json-p https://developer.github.com/v3/#json-p-callbacks
You can use it to overcome the issue with CORS.

Of course AngularJS $http service supports JSONP with method *jsonp(url, [config])*

Comment: Thanks for replying back slumber... Just one thing in my github page i am getting posts and preparing using    {% for post in site.posts %}
    { "text": {{ post.title | jsonify }}, "href": "{{ site.url }}/{{ post.url }}" },
    {% endfor %}                                                                      So how can i put this inside the data                                      "data": {
    // the data
  }

Comment: Yes you are right... The problem was coming because of extra space which i gave after the opening curly brace { "text"}...                   My Entire Solution just in case if some1 faces the same:-                  From Angular i made the call as$http.jsonp( URL?callback=JSON_CALLBACK'). Here the JSON_CALLBACK create a method dynamically which has a format angular.callbacks._0 where 0 is counter which keeps increasing everytime you make a call.. so just reset the counter before making the call using window.angular.callbacks.counter = 0. So that method name is same.